Is it necessary to explicitly wait until a compute shader is executed
I have a C++ program that uses Direct3D 11 to render images of 3D models. In that program, I'm using a compute shader to modify the content of the vertex buffer. This code works and looks as follows:
ID3D11Buffer*              nullPointer                     = nullptr;
ID3D11Buffer*              vertexBuffer                    = _vertexBuffer.get();
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* vertexBufferUnorderedAccessView = _vertexBufferUnorderedAccessView.get();
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* unorderedAccessViewNullptr[1]   = { nullptr };

_d3dContext->CSSetShader(_computeShader.get(), nullptr, 0);
_d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &nullPointer, &_vertexSize, &_offset);
_d3dContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, &vertexBufferUnorderedAccessView, nullptr);
_d3dContext->Dispatch(_threadGroupCount, 1, 1);
// Do I need to somehow block here before executing the lines below?
_d3dContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, unorderedAccessViewNullptr, nullptr);
_d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &_vertexSize, &_offset);

What I don't fully understand is whether I somehow need to block the thread that executes the above code after I call _d3dContext->Dispatch(_threadGroupCount, 1, 1). My understanding is that this line just triggers the execution of the compute shader on the GPU but then continues with executing the remaining code on the CPU without waiting for the GPU to do its processing. Unbinding the vertex buffer from the compute shader via _d3dContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, unorderedAccessViewNullptr, nullptr); should not happen before the compute shader is done executing.
My observation is that my code works as intended but I'm asking this question because in OpenGL ES 3.1, it is explicitly necessary to wait after dispatching a compute shader. This is demonstrated by the following code:
glUseProgram(_program); // _program contains the compiled compute shader
glDispatchCompute(_workGroupCount, 1, 1); // execute the compute shader
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT); // block until the compute shader execution is complete

So, my question essentially boils down to whether there is an equivalent to OpenGL's glMemoryBarrier and whether I would need to add that equivalent to my code show initially.

No. In DirectX12 you have to add a resource barrier to tell the vertex shader to wait (before it reads) for the compute shader to finish (writing). In DirectX11 the runtime does this automatically.

@TomHuntington What you say confirms the behavior I observe but I wonder whether there is at least some documentation that confirms that this is how it is intended.

glMemoryBarrier seems like a hack to me. The open OpenGL runtime does all the other memory barriers for you (that are explicit in vulkan). OpenGL is a leaky abstraction. There will be no docs in DirectX for an implementation detail they didn't leak. Try asking chatgpt about what the DirectX11 runtime does about memory/resource barriers under the hood

@TomHuntington Well, if you try sharing resources between different D3D devices, or between graphics APIs like D3D11/D3D9, you will find D3D runtime abstraction leaks as well, and you need to wait on some query or fence before consuming the updated resource on another device.
